# does RNN suitable with kaggle Titanic - Machine Learning from Disaster

Tags: csv, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, kaggle

I've found a tutorial in Kaggle web site that explains how to use RNN (Recurrent Neural Network) on the titanic data set  in order to predict who survived.

my question is - how come RNN is suitable for this problem?
I thought RNN is not suitable for problems with csv file as a data set.

link to the tutorial (you can find the csv files in there) - https://www.kaggle.com/lusob04/titanic-rnn

and here is a sample of the dataset -
[image]

and another question - do you think CNN or RL is better suited for this problem?

Comment: An RNN may indeed be unsuitable for certain *types* of data, such as independent single observations. However, whether or not a file is CSV is a very poor signal; I could have a CSV carrying timeseries that are suitable for RNN.

Comment: thanks, what about this data set? do you think RNN suitable for it?

Comment: For this data set, I would say it's not the tool I would use. I do not see a compelling reason for an RNN given in the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you suspected, RNN is not suitable for this kind of problem.

The link you shared offer a way to use RNN to solve the problem but I think using RNN in this case is an over-kill and that other, more simple models might even get you better results.